# Powershell to get full user list from old Sharepoint 2007 farm

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, stsadm

I am currently migrating an old sharepoint 2007 farm that is in an old untrusted domain. The farm has multiple sites with many levels of subsites.

I am trying to analyze the current farm to match old usernames to new ones and contact users about their content.
I have tried using sharegate, but the tool does not support such reports on 2007
I have also tried stsadm enumusers and a few variations, but it does not seem to traverse subsites

Is there a way to use powershell or stsadm to get a full export of the users of the entire farm?

Comment: Not sure if this would work on SP 2007, but have a look [here](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/12/get-all-users-of-sharepoint-site-collection-web-app-farm.html)

Comment: Yeah I was checking this script right now. I get some errors and still trying to figure if it's wrong or unsupported code

Comment: Maybe you can post what you have tried in your question including the errors you receive. Perhaps there is a SP2007 guru out there that can help you with it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.